# If you pass another object a current object's Graphics2D, would it paint on the current object?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, graphics2d

For example I have class A that extends JPanel, and I want to pass it's Graphics2D to class B. If I do operations on that Graphics2D instance in class B would it paint on class A?

```
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     super.paintComponent(g);
     Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
     ...
     b.doSomePainting(g2d);
     ...
  }
```

Comment: missing here reall question, 1) you want to Clone Custom painting from B -> A, 2) you want to pass painting from B -> A, 3) something another,

Comment: I have my panel (A), and I want to split the functionality of A so that B does all the animation but still paints onto A. If that makes sense?

Comment: http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel/code by @trashgod, there are lots of Model-> Controler-> View (MVC) examples around, but this one is nicest as I seen during a few last months

Comment: Oh so you have a control panel that manages the display panel and the logic behind it separately? That actually makes so much sense, but doesn't really address the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**. What would make you think otherwise? All you're doing is delegating the painting of the `Graphics2D` object of class `A` to class `B`. It's that simple.

Comment: I was 99% sure, and I guess it would have been easy to test it. I just wanted to check as there may have been some special rule that suggests otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: One important thing to note is that when you create the `Graphics2D` object, you should be doing the following - `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create()`. This will effectively create a copy of the `Graphics` object.

Comment: Why would that be better than just casting it?

Comment: To avoid clobbering the original `Graphics` object.

Comment: Sorry to seem a bit thick, but what do you mean by clobbering - ie. when would it be an issue?

Comment: Sometimes you already have a `Graphics` object and you want to change some of its state temporarily and then return it to its original state. One approach is to create a new `Graphics` object that is a copy of the original one and to make changes to that copy instead. This technique avoids clobbering the state of the original object, which other parts of swing may then incorrectly depend on.

Comment: +1 for delegation. For reference, this [example](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/) combines MVC with delegation; see `paintComponent()` in `RCView`.